# Cant make explicit method call from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a tabBar app with four tabs. Every tab has a camera button on the left side of each tab view's `UINavigationBar`. After clicking the camera button, entering camera mode, taking a pic, and finally selecting "Use photo", the picture should be transferred to a different ViewController and placed in a `UIImageView` that is only revealed after a method named `attachButtonInvoked` is triggered. Here is my methodology, please ignore commented lines:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];


    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);

    RGPostTableViewController *postTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postTableView"];
    RGPostViewController *postView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postView"];
    UINavigationController *postControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postControl"];



    //postView.postImageView.image = image;

    //[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [picker presentViewController:postControl animated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", image);

    [postTableView attachButtonInvoked];
    postView.postImageView.image = image;

}
```

So far I am getting the image. But I cannot successfully call `attachButtonInvoked`; it is not revealing the UIImageView and setting the picture.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be instantiating new view controllers here

```
RGPostTableViewController *postTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postTableView"];
RGPostViewController *postView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postView"];
UINavigationController *postControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postControl"];
```

rather than using the one's that have already been created. Instead, try to obtain a reference to those already instantiated view controllers so that you can set the image on the image view.